# Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS freezes randomly and permanently

Tags: 22.04, freeze, asus

I use an [ASUS X553MA](https://www.asus.com/laptops/for-home/everyday-use/x553ma/techspec/) running on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. I've been experiencing more and more frequent freezes - the laptop would freeze in the middle of the action for an indefinite amount of time and would require a hard reset for everything to go back to normal. The entire visual component would go dormant with no hint of recovery, including the cursor. `uname -r` gives `5.19.0-46-generic`.

[image: Specifications]

The laptop first froze as I was scrolling through a large .PDF textbook with quite complex illustrations, so I thought it might have been the PDF itself. Later on, even tamer PDFs would cause it to freeze, and today even a simple Google search did the trick. The laptop is indeed quite old but not unacceptably so, so I expect it to handle PDFs and simple searches free of problems. The swapfile has a reasonable size of 4.2 GB (and overall the disk space is barely occupied):
[image: swapfile]

Things I have tried so far:

- rebooting many times;
- clearing the apt cache with `sudo apt-get clean --dry-run`;
- freeing some space/cleaning residual files with `sudo apt-get autoremove` and `sudo apt-get autoclean`, as well as cleaning thumbnail cache and uninstalling apps I almost never use;
- updating/upgrading everything with `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` - everything is up-to-date;
- switch to Xorg. (no freezing yet, unsure whether the problem was solved)

At this stage, the usability of the laptop is quite a gamble which makes the whole situation very frustrating. Let me know if there are any additional resources I could provide you with (such as crash logs) for the resolution of this problem.

Comment: Troubleshooting tips: Note the time of a freeze. After restarting, check your logs around that time (both syslog and journal). Check for .crash files in /var/crash.

Comment: /var/crash is completely empty. I do not remember the exact time at which the last freeze occurred, but how would I access those logs in the future? Do I type in `sudo less /var/log/syslog` and `journalctl -b -1? How exactly would I extract the relevant logs afterwards?

Comment: When I experienced this kind of issue a couple of years ago, disabling "Automatic C-State Management" in BIOS fixed it for me. Might be called slightly differently depending on the BIOS, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: With 4G of memory, I suspect you are running out of ram and the things you have done to delete files from the disk will have no effect.  Adding swap space might help, or it might just trade locking up for getting so slow it feels like you are locking up.  You should be able to run `top` in a terminal window before using the web browser or pdf viewer to watch your memory use.

Comment: The first thing to determine is if it's a hardware or software problem. What's CPU's temperature, what are sensors reading? It may be failing RAM (`memtest` check) or SATA controller/cable. Does it occur using OS from new live USB? And yes, Linux is very bad at handling low memory scenarios (especially with vm.swappines=0).

Comment: yeah, it's most likely the ram. what a bummer

Comment: Just searching that laptop online - the memory is replaceable and the laptop can take up to 8GB. It’s worth a punt - 8Gb of ddr3 SODIMM memory is pretty cheap nowadays - I’d do that as it’s quite likely to resolve your issue.